# Whats best method to calculate multiplication mentally?

Tags: arithmetic, mental-arithmetic

I would like to know which method is better for mentally multiplication calculation between

a) Cross-Multiplication

and b) Left-to-Right Multiplication

Thank you!

Comment: Try both.  Use whatever seems to work better for you.  People's minds work in different ways.  That being said, I will *personally* often split things up if I'm struggling to give an immediate answer, such as $312\times 26 = 312\times 2\times 10 + 312\times 6 = 6240 + 1872$.  Of course, there are some special cases that make things easy, such as $95\times 105 = (100-5)(100+5)=100^2 - 5^2=9975$

Comment: More of a psychology or cognitive science question, really ...  But yes, I agree with JMorawitz: just try both yourself and see which one works for you. And I also agree with JMorawitz that there are things you can do other than Cross-mulitplication or Left-to-right multiplication to simplify your life. For example: $37 \times 49 = 37 \times 50 - 37= (37 \times 100)/2 -37 =  ...$

Comment: @JMoravitz all multiplications not equal to prime squares can be done that last way.

Comment: https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cross-multiplication ?? https://ofpad.com/multiplication-tricks-for-mental-math/ ??

Answer (score 0):

Probably neither, unless all you know is single digit multiplication. Then it comes down to which one you find quickest.

$$1225\cdot 1225=1500625$$ can be done as $$12^2\cdot100^2+2\cdot 12\cdot 25\cdot 100+25^2$$ if you know two digit multiples, and a bit of algebra ( See Karatsuba multiplication).

If you know about friendly numbers ( nearby numbers with easy multiples), then you can do more steps, but do them quicker.

Almost all multiplication of same parity except prime squares, can be don't using differences of squares, by averaging, subtracting, and subtraction of squares. a few more adds can deal with opposite parity multiplication.

In conclusion which is quickest like in computing, comes down to your relative speeds of operations.